# Как распределить все фото из одной папки по большому количеству других?

Tags: linux, bash

Есть одна большая папка, в ней более 4000 фотографий.

Необходимо распределить эти 4000 фотографий по 400 папкам, чтобы в каждой папке было по 10 фотографий.

Названия папок могут быть, например, 1, 2, 3 ... n

Как скриптиком на баше или командами это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте RenRot, пакет скорее всего есть в дистрибутиве (точно в debian, ubuntu, fedora).

Answer (score 3):

можно в каталоге с файлами выполнить такой, например, скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
d=1
while read f; do
  mkdir -p $d
  mv "$f" $d
  if [ $((n++)) -ge 10 ]; then
    n=1
    ((d++))
  fi
done < <(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```

#### чуть более короткий вариант (если имена файлов не содержат пробелов)

```
#!/bin/bash
d=1
while read l; do
  mkdir $d
  mv $l $((d++))
done < <(ls | xargs -n 10)
```

в одну строку:

```
$ d=1; while read l; do mkdir $d; mv $l $((d++)); done < <(ls | xargs -n 10)
```

---

чтобы «вернуть всё обратно» (при условии, что в этом каталоге раньше были только файлы):

```
$ find -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv {} . \;; find -type d -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы переместить файлы, с желаемыми расширениями (фото), из указанной директории по 10 штук в директории с именами 000, 001, 002, etc:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: move-images [<image-dir>]"""
import sys
from pathlib import Path

extensions = '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tif', '.tiff', '.gif', '.png'
images = [path for path in Path(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.').iterdir()
          if path.is_file() and path.suffix.lower() in extensions]
for i in range(0, len(images), 10):
    dest_dir = Path("%03d" % (i // 10))    
    dest_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    for image in images[i:i+10]:
        image.replace(dest_dir / image.name)
```